# How to login to Domino session based authentication using Postman?

Tags: authentication, xpages, lotus-domino

How can I login to a Domino session based authentication form using postman and get authenticated data. The server is setup to accept basic authentication.

Tried both POST and GET using this url but it does not seem to work

http://server/names.nsf?login&username=zzz&password=zzz&RedirectTo=http://server/database/view?readviewentries

can I access the data in one request or do I first need to authenticate using fomr-data and later get data?

any other way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Authorization tab select Basic Auth as type and add your username and password.

[image]

Comment: thx, didn't see the forrest becuase of the trees :-)

Comment: Noite that this is not "session authentication" per se, and it follows the ancient "realm" rules of very early web security -- although that won't be an issue for you as long as you are using 'http://server/names.nsf' for the URI since that sets the realm to 'server' (i.e., the second to last node in the URL, excluding arguments).

Comment: Also note that with an 'http' prefix instead of 'https', you are sending passwords in the clear. They can be intercepted.